# Setting CSS3 gradient properties with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm writing a plugin that is reliant on CSS3 gradient background properties. I have no problem getting something like this to work:

```
$(this).css({ '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 2px 2px 5px #DEDEDE' });
```

However, this fails to work:

```
$(this).css({ 'background': '-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f4f4f4),to(#FFFFFF))' });
```

I was under the assumption that .css() worked with any property supported by the browser so I'm either setting it wrong with jQuery or this property isn't supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt the first example works either: if you want to set css property, you have to use two parameters, like `$(this).css('background', '-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f4f4f4),to(#FFFFFF))');​​​​​​​`

More on the subject:
http://api.jquery.com/css/

**edit**
You're right, it's possible to set css properties with `{name:value}` notation, they just don't tell it in the function summary (you have to read further on).
Anyway, here's the working example with two parameters (the second one from your post): http://jsfiddle.net/BX9Wa/

Comment: Also works: `$(this).css({ 'background': '-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom,rgb(255,255,255) 0%,rgb(241,250,254) 100%)' });`

Comment: Also works: `$(this).css({ 'filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4cdbff, endColorstr=#FFFFFF)' })` AND `$(this).css({ '-ms-filter': '\"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#f4f4f4, endColorstr=#FFFFFF)\"' })`. LOL.

Comment: This is quite annoying. From messing around with this, it seems you cannot mix `.css({ 'someProp':'someSetting' })` with `.css( 'someProp','someSetting' )`. The only property that doesn't work with the former is the webkit gradient. Even the IE filter gradients work with that syntax! Unless I am screwing something up again, my only solution to do this is to chain a ton of `.css( 'someProp','someSetting' )` together or not be able to use the webkit gradient.